# Python: Order fits-file pixel by brightness, ignore artefacts

Tags: python, astronomy, fits

I have 4000 fits-files images from SPITZER, each containing the same star over a time period. Each image is a photmetry cube of 32 pixel * 32 pixel * 64 consequent time frames. I need to look through all the single frames and order the pixel by brightness. Not hard to do with Python, but sometimes I have in the frames short-lived events/artefacts which are brighter than the brightest pixel of the star (see below). These artefacts last only over one or two consequent time frames

How can I easily correct for the artefacts? Is there an astropy/pyfits package that does this? Or some kind of bad pixel flagging in SPITZER (I know that Kepler-images have flagging of bad pixel)?

Optional: It would be convenient to have the code in vectorized form, avoiding loops, so that I save computtional time

---

Comparison of two frames, in the left one everything is fine, in the right one you see in the top right corner one of this artefacts, being brighter than any of the star pixel. Note: the artefact doesn't reach the level of saturation.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "correct for the artifacts"? How are they represented? Are they just `inf`s in the arrays?

Comment: @Iguananaut - I added a frame containing the artefact. They are not "inf", they have values below a saturation limit. By "correct for the artefacts" I mean python code, which will cause my function that is searching for the brightest pixel to ignore this artefact and instead efficiently locate the star as the brightest pixel/source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following an advice to "just google it", I found an astropy-function - DAOStarFinder - that does what I was looking for. It scans an image for light-sources and one can set threshold for a detection, e.g. the "roundness", "sharpness" or brightness of an object have to be between [-0.05,0.05], [0.6,0.8] or >5*standard_deviation, respectively. I must say, that I have the impression the roundness and sharpness measure don't work consistently and sometimes values for the same object change enormously from one frame to the other. But DAOStarFinder gives you also a rough estimate of the flux density of the object, which I could use for sorting the sources and filtering out the relevant one. Here is a link to [example script](http://photutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/detection.html) and to the [documentation](http://photutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/photutils.DAOStarFinder.html) of DAOStarFinder. And here the example script explicitly:

```
>>> from astropy.stats import sigma_clipped_stats
>>> from photutils import datasets
>>> from photutils import DAOStarFinder

>>> hdu = datasets.load_star_image()    
>>> data = hdu.data[0:400, 0:400]    
>>> mean, median, std = sigma_clipped_stats(data, sigma=3.0, iters=5)
>>> daofind = DAOStarFinder(fwhm=3.0, threshold=5.*std)    
>>> sources = daofind(data - median)    

>>> print(sources)
```